# How to synchronize the existing client-side database between another clients and server?

Tags: android, client-server, data-synchronization

**Of course, I don't ask to you post me code of client and server.** I just never make it early. I want understand logic of this process.

Now, I have an Android app that has different data in the database of different users. (Data can be different on each device of user). And I need to write a server and update my app-client to support the data synchronization.

What problem I have at now? I cannot understand how to remove items from database if client cannot connect to server at this moment (to I can remove data on server I need to save all removed items until app-client hasn't connection to a server)

How to correct synchronize time and etc.

How to store transaction log on client? For example, user modifies a some item but client hasn't connection. How can server understand that this I item was modified?

I will very glad any help by my theme and any links and docs.

P.S. Sorry for my English. I'm really noobie in this and due to my bad English cannot find details docs.

P.S.S. If you need more details, please, write me I'll add.

**ADDED**

My current model. I took a simple table for example.

Client has local table with fields:

- ID - local ID
- SID - server ID (null before first synchronization of the row)
- Revision - local revision of the row
- Flag

  - m - has local modification
  - n - hasn't any modification
  - d - was removed
- another fields

Server table has:
 - ID - server ID
 - Rev - revision of the row in the server database

**Logic**

- If row in client database hasn't SID it's a new row: add it in server database and set revision 0, on client set revision 0 too and server ID for this row.
- If row in client with SID not found in server database it will removed in client database.
- If row in client database with SID like revision in the server
  database and flag 'm' then update row in the server database and
  increment revision in both databases. (So if some devices has all
  same revision and flag only first connected device write changes in
  the server database; all another clients just gets this update from
  the server and loses their).
- If client row has flag 'd' and SID then
  it will remove everywhere.

I don't write all cases I think it's understandable. What's bad in my model. How can I improve it? I cannot use timestamp because clock on different devices can have a different time.

Comment: "there's only two hard problems in computer science-  cache invalidation and naming things".  You need a LOT more info to accurately answer your question.  Keeping multiple copies of a db in sync is tremendously difficult.

Comment: I'm also interested in this ...I will keep an eye

Comment: It isn't a problem. I can write difficult system and develop first synchronize model for this purpose. But although it works it has a lot of problems (a lot of garbage data - not useful for users) and etc. So I want know how professional developers make it. But cannot find samples suitable for my case. Only when server store database and client connect to it and client haven't offline mode to edit database.

Comment: @gabe-sechan, I added more details by my problem.